# SQL using regular expression REGEXP_LIKE()

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-like

I'm having some issues where I can't seem the like regex to match 3 or more a's or e's in the name.

Find all managers that manage employees with at least 3 letters 'a' or 'e' in their name (both uppercase
and lowercase). For instance having 2 'a' and 1 'e' in the name, will satisfy the selection criteria

```
select manager_name
  from manages
 where regexp_like(employee_name, '[a,e]{3, }');
```

When I do this it shows a proper list with an 'e' or 'a' in it, but when I try to do 3 or more it returns blank set.  Also sample data provided below.

```
select manager_name
  from manages
 where regexp_like(employee_name, '[a,e]');
```

Sample Data

```
William Gates III
Lakshmi Mittal
Ingvar Kamprad
Lawrence Ellison
Mark Zuckerberg
Sheryl Sandberg
Liliane Bettencourt
Michael Dell
```

Comment: Can you share some sample input and explain how the returned output is wrong. Also, which [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: `[aAeE]{3,}` is the good regex

Comment: Oracle, and it returns a blank set when it isn't supposed to.

Comment: Also I don't know why I got downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for this instead

```
(.*[ae]){3,}
```

The `.*` accepts differents chars between those wanted

So your query becomes:

```
select manager_name
  from manages
  where 
  regexp_like(employee_name, '(.*[ae]){3,}', 'i');
```

The `i` flag is for insensitive match, so capital `AE` are taken into account to... If ommitted, sensitive match is performed...

You can also use simply `{3}` instead of `{3,}`, it will produce the same results in this case

Comment: what does the .* do?   Any one character one or more times?

Comment: What does the 'i' do at the end of that query?

Comment: The `'i'` is the match parameter and tells Oracle to do a case-insensitive search. `.*` is any character (`.`) zero or more times (`*`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want at least 3 `a`'s or `e`'s anywhere in the name then:

```
select manager_name
from   manages
where  regexp_like(employee_name, '(.*?[ae]){3,}', 'i' );
```

If you want at least 3 consecutive `a`'s or `e`s then:

```
select manager_name
from   manages
where  regexp_like(employee_name, '.*[ae]{3,}', 'i' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try using `REGEXP_COUNT()` instead of `REGEXP_LIKE()`:

```
SELECT manager_name
  FROM manages
 WHERE REGEXP_COUNT(employee_name, '[ae]', 1, 'i') >= 3;
```

The value of the third parameter in `REGEXP_COUNT()` indicates the position of where the search should start (in this case, we want to start at the beginning) while the `match_parameter 'i'` indicates that the search should be case-insensitive.

`REGEXP_COUNT()` was added with Oracle 11g; if you're using an earlier edition of Oracle then you can try the following:

```
SELECT manager_name
  FROM manages
 WHERE REGEXP_INSTR(employee_name, '[ae]', 1, 3, 0, 'i') > 0;
```

The fourth parameter above (`3`) is the number of the occurrence of the regular expression.

or:

```
SELECT manager_name
  FROM manages
 WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(employee_name, '[ae]', 1, 3, 'i') IS NOT NULL;
```

Either way it makes the regular expression simpler than if you use `REGEXP_LIKE()`.